# How to edit (CSS) LightDM GTK+ Greeter

Tags: lightdm, login-screen

Is there a manual or does anyone know how to edit the (CSS) files for the LightDM GTK+ Greeter? I'm already using LightDM Greeter Settings, but I want more customization. Somehow the webkit greeter doesn't work properly on my system (themes are not showing up they way they should), so I'm hoping there is a way to just edit the "standard" greeter.

Comment: Try http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

Comment: If it's CSS, you can look up help for whatever you need on that, or just experiment.

Comment: There is not really a page (Googled it) with information on how to customize it. But I read a lot about theming it via CSS within your installed theme. But where should it be stored and how should it look like? That's something I can't find...

Comment: Start [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to A.B. I found that the CSS settings are imported into `gtk.css` in the GTK theme you use. The CSS file itself is named `lightdm-gtk-greeter.css` and should be in `/usr/share/themes/(theme)/apps/`

Comment: Please, if you are not looking for other answer, could you accept this (your own), see [self-answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)